# Javascript Object instantiated inside its declaration

Tags: javascript

Can someone explain how this works. An object checks to see if it has been instantiated, and if it hasn't, then instantiates itself. It reminds me of a singleton, but I am not sure if I understand this code correctly.

```
var circularBuffer = function (size) {

    if (this instanceof  circularBuffer) {
        this.size = size;
        this.clear();
    } else {
        return new circularBuffer(size);
    }

};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This pattern makes sure that whether you call `circularBuffer` with `new` or not, you still get a new instance.

So both of the following result in a new `circularBuffer` instance being assigned to `cb`:

```
var cb = new circularBuffer(100);

var cb = circularBuffer(100);
```

In the first case, `this` is a `circularBuffer` instance so it follows the `if` path.  In the second case, `this` is `window` so the method follows the `else` path and will re-call itself using `new` instead.

Comment: Wich is equivalent of this:
`var circularBuffer = function (size) {

    if (window.circularBuffer) {
        this.size = size;
        this.clear();
    } else {
        return new circularBuffer(size);
    }

};`